# La mejor manera de consultar una gran cantidad de datos con MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una colección de 1.6GB que básicamente tienen 2 datos: `nombre` y `documento`.

El documento tiene esta estructura:

```
{
  "_id":  ObjectId("5a6ba42850c4631898754a06"),
  "nombre": "Jorge",
  "documento": "4918273627"
}
```

Yo los busco por `documento` y me devuelve el `nombre`.

Mi duda es si hay alguna forma de optimizarlo para que los resultados aparezcan más rápido, porque la consulta tarda un buen tiempo y entiendo que este tipo de bases de datos son mucho más veloces que las relacionales.

La consulta la hago con Mongoose en NodeJS y es la siguiente:

```
    MongoDB.collection('datos').findOne({ 'documento': { $regex: new RegExp("^" + documento.toLowerCase(), 'i') } }, function (error, ok) {
```

Gracias por sus aportes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solamente estás buscando las **coincidencias exactas**, deberías utilizar el operador [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#op._S_eq):

```
'documento': { 
    $eq: documento
}
```

- No tiene sentido usar un regex cuando estás buscando una coincidencia exacta.

---

Pero si estás buscando "todos los documentos que empiecen con...", como en el código de tu pregunta, viendo que los documentos son números, no tiene sentido usar el modificador `i` para ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas. El problema de ignorar mayúsculas/minúsculas en MongoDB es que desactiva los índices en la búsqueda, haciendo que sea muuuuuuuuuucho menos eficiente.

Para encontrar los documentos **que empiezan con**:

```
'documento': { 
    $regex: '^' + documento
}
```

---

Por supuesto, asegurate de haber creado un índice para `documento` con [**db.collection.createIndex()**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/). Eso te va a asegurar que la búsqueda sea rápida.

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias. Lo probé y está rapidísimo.